# WifiInfo.getMacAddress() returns 02:00:00:00:00:00 aways in Android 6.0 device

Tags: android

I have learned that since the Android 6.0:

> Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware
>   identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The
>   WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress()
>   methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00。

But,what I confused is when my **targetSdkVersion** is lower than 23 it still returns the constant in android 6.0 device. In my opinion, I think it should return an unique hardware identifier because of the **Application forward compatibility**. Whay did not system enable any compatibility behaviors ? 
This is my uses-sdk:

```
 android:minSdkVersion="8"
 android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```

This is my method:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Thanks.Forgive my broken English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did not system enable any compatibility behaviors ?

For sake of data protection, we are not entitled to this kind of **forward compatibility**. Your app still runs , right? So it is forward compatible. but security loopholes must be addressed even if it hurts someone's legitimate purpose.

And sending a constant value `02:00:00:00:00:00` is a compatibility behavior otherwise they would have just return `null` value

Comment: I seem to understand some， Thank you for answering my first question on Stackvoerflow.

Comment: you need to accept the answer if it satisfied your question. Thanks!